# "Linear" functions notation

Tags: notation

can anybody explain me why a "linear" function is represented by $Ax-b$?

I do not think that a linear function is meant in my text, as $Ax-b$ doesn't map $0$ to $0$ if $b\ne 0$. So, if that is an affine function (that I used to see in the form $mx+b$), why is that written involving matrices?

Comment: I'm confused by this question; what is the text to which you are referring? It is true that the term "linear function" can refer to two different concepts (i.e. it can mean $ax+b$ in some algebraic contexts - despite this actually being affine - and just $Ax$ in others), but it's hard to say more than that without more context.

Comment: $y=A x-b$ represents a line on the plane, as a geometric figure, which is why it is commonly called linear. This does not match the definition used in linear algebra, but not everyone is always careful to distinguish "linear" from "affine ".

Comment: @MiloBrandt well, there are many funny things in math. The funniest is notations.

Comment: @Wouter so, it is like a "true" linear function, but shifted on $b$? Why then there is $-b$ is the formula, not just $+b$?

Comment: @Kirill Yes. $b$ is presumably assumed to be a (possibly negative) real number, so functions of the form $a x+b$ are the same set of functions as those of the form $a x - b$.

Comment: It think you are confusing "linear function" with "linear transformation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the way we use these notions. You are right, it should technically be affine, but it is often simply called linear. Similarly to orthogonal matrices, which should technically be called *orthonormal* matrices etc.

Comment: but why the matrix $A$ for the notation, not $m$?

Comment: @Kirill Because we are not in one dimension here. $m$ is just the 1D special case of a matrix $A$. In higher dimensions we need matrices to describe all possible transformations. Are you familiar with vector spaces and (actually) linear maps given by matrices?

Comment: yes @M.Winter. That is why I am wondering about that. Do we really have lines in higher dimensions, or are these planes, forms or something else there?

Comment: @Kirill We have lines in arbitrary high dimensions. But the term "linear" in "linear transformation" (or affine transformation in your case) has little to do with lines anymore. It is just a name you should get used to. Affine transformations "preserve lines", which is why they are named linear usually. They are not called like this because they describe lines or give a plot which looks like a line.